# Spark parquet schema evolution

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I have a partitioned hdfs parquet location which is having different schema is different partition.

Say 5 columns in first partition, 4 cols in 2nd partition. Now I try to read the base Parquet path and then filter the 2nd partition.

This gives me 5 columns in the DF even though I have only 4 columns in Parquet files in 2nd partition. 
When I read the 2nd partition directly, it gives correct 4 cols. How to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the required `schema(4 columns)` while reading the parquet file!

- Then spark only reads the fields that included in the **`schema`**, if field not exists in the data then **`null`** will be returned.

**`Example:`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val sch=new StructType().add("i",IntegerType).add("z",StringType)
spark.read.schema(sch).parquet("<parquet_file_path>").show()

//here i have i in my data and not have z field
//+---+----+
//|  i|   z|
//+---+----+
//|  1|null|
//+---+----+
```

Comment: I am applying my own schema but it has only 4 columns as available in 2nd partition. I am reading the base directory which has multiple partitions. My DF schema is having 5 cols as partition 1 files having 5 schema. Even after filtering only partition 2, I am still having 5 cols in my DF

Comment: while reading did you add **`.schema(<new_schema>)`** and then read the parquet directory? parquet will only pull the data for the specified schema only if we specify .schema option or else it will read all fields!

Comment: No I don&#39;t add schema while reading itself. It infers schema and then I convert it to rdd, do some processing, finally create a dataframe with schema. Here in this schema I m giving only 4 cols but the rdd is already having 5 cols. So data is getting shifted from the 5th col if I have 100 cols

Answer (score 1):

I would really like to hep you but I am not sure what you actually want to achieve. What's your intention about this?

If you to read the parquet file with all it's partitions and you just wanna get the columns both partitions have, maybe the read option "mergeSchema" fits your need.

> Like Protocol Buffer, Avro, and Thrift, Parquet also supports schema evolution. Users can start with a simple schema, and gradually add more columns to the schema as needed. In this way, users may end up with multiple Parquet files with different but mutually compatible schemas. The Parquet data source is now able to automatically detect this case and merge schemas of all these files.
>
> Since schema merging is a relatively expensive operation, and is not a
> necessity in most cases, we turned it off by default starting from
> 1.5.0. You may enable it by setting data source option mergeSchema to true when reading Parquet files (as shown in the examples below), or
> setting the global SQL option spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema to true.

refer to [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html)

so it would be interesting which version of spark you are using and how the properties  `spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema` (spark setting) and `mergeSchema` (client) are set

Comment: Yes exactly. I want only the schemas which are common in all partition. Partition 1 has 5 cols, partition 2 has 4 cols so I should be getting only 4 cols in DF when I read this file as the 5th column in partition 1 is not available in partition 2 but I am getting 5 cols in my DF even after filtering the DF to have only partition 2. But the actual Parquet files inside partition 2 doesn't have that 5th column and spark inserts null for this column which I don't want. I want only 4 cols in my DF when I filter partition 2

Comment: okay, now that I got you I think the easiest and most reliable way to solve this is what @Shu just said. But it's not generic and I love generic, reusable solutions. Did you already have a look at the ```mergeSchema``` option when reading the partitioned Parquet file?

Comment: I can't give the .schema and read bcz I will convert to rdd and  manipulating the data after reading and finally , I will again convert to DF with the schema here. As of now I have made changes to read the direct partition directory, in this case, I don't get partition column in the DF so I add it manually but as I read one partition, it gives correct schema which is available inside that partition alone unlike previous method where it gave extra schemas